# How to fix the The prop `onBackdropClick` of `ForwardRef(Modal)` is deprecated. Use the onClose prop with the `reason` argument ? MUI

Tags: material-ui

Can't fix the Material UI warning in console:
`index.js:1` Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `onBackdropClick` of `ForwardRef(Modal)` is deprecated. Use the `onClose` prop with the `reason` argument to handle the `backdropClick` events.

The `<Popup/>` component is taken from the devexrpess library.

```
`<Popup
    onHiding={() => setIsOpen(false)}
    width={400}
    height={400}
    showTitle={true}
    title={'Add New Calendar'}
    dragEnabled={true}
    visible={isOpen}
    contentRender={content}
    showCloseButton={false}
    closeOnOutsideClick={true}
  />`
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Clearly the warning tells you to swap the `onBackdropClick` with the new function `onClose`

Comment: @KiaKaha Hi there ,  actualy i'm using the popup from react Devexpress wich in it's turn is based on a lot of MUI components . I've edited my request with some code if it helps and thank you in advance :D

Comment: Could you add a link to the dev express docs? Maybe the issues on their side and it is possible there's nothing you could do until they update their package

Comment: Here is the requested link for Devexpress docs : https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/

Answer (score 0):

Obviously devexpress is wrapping the MUI components. It is not stated in the docs if this could help but very often there are props which are not described in the docs so you can give it a try:

```
   const handleClose = (event, reason) => {
    if (disableBackdropClick && reason === "backdropClick") {
      return false;
    }

    if (disableEscapeKeyDown && reason === "escapeKeyDown") {
      return false;
    }

    if (typeof onClose === "function") {
      onClose();
    }
  };

  return (
    <Popup onClose={handleClose} {...rest}>
      {children}
    </Popup>
  );
```

[source](https://robertmarshall.dev/blog/disablebackdropclick-of-forwardrefdialog-is-deprecated-solution-and-example/)

Comment: Hi there ! Thank you for your help, it did not work for me i still get the warning but i've contacted the devExpress support and they're fixing it and as soon as they provide a hotfix i'll close this ticket...thanks again :D

Comment: That's a good resolution, you're welcome - good luck!

Comment: @Safouene did you resolve this? I am facing the same issue.